# how to submit data in Jquery Mobile from parent to dialogue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuerymobile, but i know jquery already. I have got an assignment recently were i have button, when i press that, i need to get the related data opened in the jQuery mobile dialogue.

Consider the dialogue box contains table list, each row in the table list contains button, so when i click the button, we need to load another dialogue box with some related information from the current dialogue.

The dialogue box is a linked one in jquery mobile.

Here i want to know how we can post the data from main page to the dialogue box on clicking the anchor button or a normal button.

Can any one have any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use locationStorage.

**STORING DATA**

```
var NameData = "dataURL";

localStorage.setItem("data", NameData);
```

**USING DATA(ANOTHER PAGE OR SAME PAGE)**

```
var myData = localStorage.getItem("data");

alert(myData);
```